# Duplicate content: two pages with just a little change in code are still considered duplicate content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have a website which talks about cars and motorcycles. Once in, the user can choose wether to browse the cars section or the motorcycles section. Once chosen his section, the url will have a `/section/` part in it.

The page requests are always the same. The difference is just about the content.

The structure of a common page is the following:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+    SLIDER WITH PHOTOS   +
+  AND SMALL DESCRIPTION  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

       PAGE CONTENT

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

If i am browsing the car section, the slider will be populated with car photos and some text about car. Else, if i am browsing the motorcycles section, some bikes with some text will populate the slider.

**EXAMPLE**

Let's take as example the **news** page. If i am browsing the cars section, my URL will be `mywebsite.com/cars/news`. Else, if i am browsing the motorcycles section, the url will be `mywebsite.com/motorcycles/news`.

Here is the trick! My website in both situations will run the script `news.php`. Different news will be displayed, because basing on URL, different posts will be fetched from db.

This means, `mywebsite.com/cars/news` and `mywebsite.com/motorcycles/news` will not generate duplicate content, because the content delivered is totally different.

**THE PROBLEM**

Let's take as example the **about us** page. In this page i show information about the website. These information are the same wether i am browsing the car section or the motorcycles section.

This means, if i visit `mywebsite.com/cars/about-us` or `mywebsite.com/motorcycles/about-us` the slider part (and some other little menus) will be slightly different, having different pictures and descriptions, but the page content will be exactly the same.

**THE QUESTIONS**

1. Being (in the **about-us** page example) 90% of the page identical,
   will crawlers see it as duplicate content (and penalize me)? More in general, what crawlers consider as duplicated content are two identical pages or two ALMOST identical pages?
2. Should I decide which one is the best version and put
   `rel="canonical"` in it?

**NOTE:** I would prefer not removing `/section/` from my URLS, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Google might consider a page as duplicate if it finds the entire content of a web page in other web page and in order to solve this issue we have to use `rel=canonical` attribute.
2. Yes! You should use `rel="canonical"` in the `<head>` section of  `mywebsite.com/cars/about-us` or `mywebsite.com/motorcycles/about-us`.

For example:

If you put

```
<link rel="canonical" href="mywebsite.com/cars/about-us"/>
```

in the `<head>` section of `mywebsite.com/motorcycles/about-us` it will tell Google to consider `mywebsite.com/cars/about-us` page instead of considering both the pages.